# Finding elements on Xamarin Test Recorder

Tags: android, testing, xamarin, recorder

I am new using on Xamarin Test Recorder and I am not able to find a proper documentation to help me identify specific elements in the app.

By, example, I am trying to automate the use of a date selector, however, even if I specify the exact point where I want to click using the coordinates, the recorder tends to not find the element I want and stops the test.

I know that this is not web automation, but I am not sure if I could be able to find another way to automate those controls.

Any suggestions? Any place where I can be able to read something that could help?

Answer (score 0):

In general to click on an element using the ID you defined in the application layout. You need the following code:

```
app.Tap(x => x.Id("elementId"));
```

Maybe the element is not the UI yet while executing the code, in that case you need to add a wait for element:

```
app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("elementId"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: The problem with the control I am editing is the fact that the element, the date selector, is found by the recorder with only the Class "SimpleMonthView", however there is no way to define in which part exactly I can click.

I mean, if I want to click on a specific day of the calendar there is no way Test Recorder would find the point and it should use coordenates instead, but take in account that I am expecting to use the script to apply it to other devices..